# Can approve function be malicious?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin, erc-20-approve

I'm so confused on how approve functions works:

If myToken contract has an approve function but the owner did not approve the contract B. Then contract B deploys a function and create a function that calls mytoken.approve of a user then transfer user tokens to contract B. Is it possible?

For example myToken contract is a ERC20 Contract.

Can I create a contract StealTokens to approve and transfer tokens from myToken contract?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract MyToken {
    string public name = "MyToken";
    string public symbol = "MT";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    address public owner; // The owner of the token contract

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);

    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10**uint256(decimals);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= value, "ERC20: insufficient balance");

        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= value;
        balanceOf[to] += value;

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(balanceOf[from] >= value, "ERC20: insufficient balance");
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, "ERC20: allowance exceeded");

        balanceOf[from] -= value;
        balanceOf[to] += value;
        allowance[from][msg.sender] -= value;

        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the ERC-20 `approve()` function relies on the `msg.sender` value to decide who to approve the tokens on behalf of, this means that the person that calls `approve()` can only allow other users to spend their balance, not any one else's.

Look at the very first line of code inside the `approve()` function:

`allowance[msg.sender][spender] = amount;`

You can see that this sets the allowance value at `msg.sender` for the `spender`.

For example If **Alice** calls `approve()` with **Bob**'s address as the `spender` and 100 as the `amount`, the amount of tokens **Bob** is allowed to spend on behalf of **Alice** is set to `100`.

You can test the effects of `approve()` by using the view function `allowance()`, this function allows anyone to view how many tokens a `spender` is allowed to take/spend on behalf of the `owner`. To fit our previous example, if you called `allowance()`, with **Alice**'s address as the `owner` and **Bob**'s address as the `spender`, you should see `100` returned as the result since **Alice** just approved **Bob** to spend that.

`allowance(aliceAddr, bobAddr) public view returns(remaining)`

remaining is the amount that can be spent, aka the value at `allowance[aliceAddr][bobAddr]`

To put this in perspective for you, if you wanted to create a malicous `approve()` function that could set the allowance for any user by and user, it would be as simple as adding an additional input param to the function, or even just changing the function logic a little:

Malicious approve with new input:

```js
function approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        allowance[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
        return true;
    }
```

Malicious approve with changed input:

```js
function approve(address owner, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        allowance[owner][msg.sender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, msg.sender, amount);
        return true;
    }
```

Both of these malicious `approve()` functions allow anyone to increase their allowance on behalf of another user, this is behavior that is obviously unwanted in most cases.